# How to setup az library on CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, python, azure-cli

I am trying to use [az](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest) library on `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`, but when I run `az --version` the following message is shown.

```
[azure@cdh-raw-master ~]$ az --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    ﻿__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import re
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

I am tried to use python 2 and 3, but I had same issues. I installed `az` using following commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "[azure-cli]\nname=AzureCLI\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/azure-cli.repo'
sudo yum install azure-cli
```

I installed python3 using following command:

```
sudo yum install rh-python36
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same, I downgraded from 2.0.70 to 2.0.64

```
sudo yum downgrade azure-cli-2.0.64
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris Tatro! Unfortunately, that version did not work for me. I am download and installing rpms from repository at https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli/. Are there another tip you can tell me to fix that?